# Зупинитися на зупинці - як краще сказати?

Tags: вживання-слів

Як краще попросити водія зупинити маршрутку на зупинці?

"Зупиніться на зупинці" - якось не дуже.

Чув ще "станьте на зупинці" - тавтології нема, але чи це краще?

Який варіант уникає тавтології і є літературним?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. На зупинці, будь ласка.
2. На наступній, будь ласка.
3. На `назва зупинки у місцевому відмінку`, будь ласка.
4. Зупиніть на `назва зупинки у місцевому відмінку`, будь ласка.

Якщо без "будь ласка", то перші два варіанти наче звучать грубо, але ввічлива форма звертання виправдовує скорочення до двох слів.

Answer (score 5):

Я б сказав "зупиніться, будь ласка, на <назва зупинки>". Також пропонується варіант "станьте на зупинці", якщо пошукати подібні дискусії в Інтернеті.

Answer (score 1):

Уявіть собі роботу водія маршрутки. Він має вести машину, приймати гроші, давати решту й зупинятися, де його попросять. Зрозуміло, що коли ви називаєте йому місце, то ви просите його там зупинитися, тому саме слово «зупиніться» є абсолютно зайвим. Я вважаю, що ввічливість – це важливо, тому я завжди додам «будь ласка» до чого б я не прохав водія.

Ідеальним варіянтом прохання зупинити я вважаю вислів типу «[місце зупинки], будь ласка»: «на зупинці, будь ласка», «біля магазину, будь ласка», тощо.

Comment: В цілому погоджуюся, але на мою думку, з практичної точки зору, коли в маршрутці багато людей і до того ж шумить мотор, потрібне якесь ключове слово щоб привернути увагу водія. Можливо це і є "будь ласка", а можливо щось, що починається із "зупи(-нка, -ніть)".

Answer (score -1):

Зупинку треба означити якось географічно або в часі — тоді буде абсолютно правильне звертання.

Comment: Ласкаво просимо на сайт Ukrainian Language.SE! Будь ласка, почитайте [про наші критерії](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/5/), за якими ми оцінюємо хороші відповіді. Цей допис не відповідає таким критеріям: він виглядає як суб'єктивна і нічим не підтверджена думка. Окрім того, вона мало стосується мови як такої.

Comment: @bytebuster, до речі, по-моєму, абсолютно правильна відповідь. Бо фраза «зупиніть на зупинці» некоректна не тавтологією, а, в першу чергу, відсутністю інформації — на якій саме зупинці: на наступній, на найближчній серед тих, про які колектив раніше домовився не пропускати, на якійсь іншій… Із вказанням конкретики і фраза набирає змісту з формальної точки зору, і зникає чи менш кидається у вічі тавтологія. Якби автор ще трішки свою відповідь розширив…